# Calling a GenServer from another GenServer

Tags: elixir, gen-server

I have a project where I use 2 GenServers
The first GenServer named "State" maintains the state, the second GenServer named "Updates" maintains a list of possible updates to the state. What I want to achieve is:

With every call to "State", "State" should call "Updates" and update itself before returning the actual state.

Both GenServers are started by a supervisor and I can call both GenServers by name from outside but if I try to call the API of "Updates" inside of "State", "State" terminates with a "no process" error. Any suggestions?

```
  def start_link(opts) do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, opts, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(_arg) do
    children = [
      {Updates, name: Updates},
      {State, name: State}
    ]

    Supervisor.init(children, strategy: :rest_for_one)
  end
```

Both GenServer start with

```
  def start_link(opts) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], opts)
  end
```

In "State" I have the callback

```
  @impl true
  def handle_call({:get}, _from, state) do
    updates = Updates.get_updates(Updates)
    {:reply, updates, state}
  end
```

Again, if I call Updates.get_updates(Updates) for example from iex directly everything works as expected, so I think everything is fine with my supervisor. It seems just like "State" does not know the name of "Updates".

Updates.get_updates/1 implementation is:

```
  def get_updates(pid) do
    GenServer.call(pid, :get)
  end
```

where the callback is just the state as reply

```
  @impl true
  def handle_call(:get, _from, state) do
    {:reply, state, state}
  end
```

Comment: Please post the code for the function `Updates.get_updates/1`

Comment: If `State` GenServer has a dependency on `Update` GenServer, then `Update` should be started before `State`, to ensure it is available, before `State` tries to call it

Comment: included implementation of Updates.get_updates/1 in the question. @PawełObrok

Comment: I thought the supervisor starts the children synchronously in the order, they are given, so `State` should be started before `Updates` @PawełDawczak

Comment: another addition: `State` has no dependency on `Upgrades`on startup. It uses `Upgrades`when it is called. At this time, mix should have made sure, that both GenServers are started.

Comment: @Sorebrez it doesn't seem by your description that this would be problematic, nonetheless it's logical to have the genserver that has any kind of dependency on another be started after the one it depends on. This also allows you to then use a restart strategy of `rest_for_all`, which ensures that if the genserver that is dependable on is shut, the workers started afterwards that depend on it are restarted too - it makes errors more visible overall.

Comment: And you should post the `Updates.get_updates/1` the "implementation" you've post doesn't show what it's doing nor how it gets the pid

Comment: @m3characters this makes totally sense! I changed the order in the children list of the supervisor but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: @m3characters The `Updates.get_updates/1` does nothing but calling the GenServer in the posted handle_call. Sorry, I made a naming mistake there - corrected it in the question. The `pid`argument is the :name which is `Updates`

Comment: When you start the application you're starting the supervisor that starts these right? Perhaps you can upload a repo somewhere?

Comment: @m3characters Exactly, they are started correctly. From iex i can call them both without any problems. Just the call from inside `State` to `Updates` does not function. I will try to set up a repo with a minimal example later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> State" terminates with a "no process" error. Any suggestions?

According to the [Supervisor docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html), the `children` list:

```
   children = [
      {Updates, name: Updates},
      {State, name: State}
    ]
```

should be a list of `child specification` tuples, where a child specification has the following valid keys:

> The child specification contains 6 keys. The first two are required,
>   and the remaining ones are optional:
>
> **:id** - any term used to identify the child specification internally by
>   the supervisor; defaults to the given module. In the case of
>   conflicting :id values, the supervisor will refuse to initialize and
>   require explicit IDs. This key is required.
>
> **:start** - a tuple with the module-function-args to be invoked to start
>   the child process. This key is required.
>
> **:restart** - an atom that defines when a terminated child process should
>   be restarted (see the “Restart values” section below). This key is
>   optional and defaults to :permanent.
>
> **:shutdown** - an atom that defines how a child process should be
>   terminated (see the “Shutdown values” section below). This key is
>   optional and defaults to 5000 if the type is :worker or :infinity if
>   the type is :supervisor.
>
> **:type** - specifies that the child process is a :worker or a
>   :supervisor. This key is optional and defaults to :worker.
>
> There is a sixth key, **:modules**, that is rarely changed. It is set
>   automatically based on the value in :start.

Note that there is no `name:` key, which you are listing in your child specifications.

However, `GenServer.start_link()` does have a `name:` option:

> Both start_link/3 and start/3 support the GenServer to register a name
>   on start via the :name option. Registered names are also automatically
>   cleaned up on termination. The supported values are:
>
> **an atom** - the GenServer is registered locally with the given name using Process.register/2.
>
> **{:global, term}** - the GenServer is registered globally with the given term using the functions in the :global module.
>
> **{:via, module, term}** - the GenServer is registered with the given mechanism and name. The :via option expects a module that exports
>   register_name/2, unregister_name/1, whereis_name/1 and send/2. One
>   such example is the :global module which uses these functions for
>   keeping the list of names of processes and their associated PIDs that
>   are available globally for a network of Elixir nodes. Elixir also
>   ships with a local, decentralized and scalable registry called
>   Registry for locally storing names that are generated dynamically.
>
> For example, we could start and register our Stack server locally as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> # Start the server and register it locally with name:
>
> MyStack {:ok, _} = GenServer.start_link(Stack, [:hello], name: MyStack)
> ```

So, I think you should be doing something like this:

```
  def init(_arg) do
    children = [
      Updates,
      State
    ]
```

Then in your GenServer start_link() functions:

```
 def start_link(args) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, args, name: __MODULE__)
 end
```

======

Here is a full example.  In `application.ex`, you *could* specify the names that you want to register:

```
children = [
  # Starts a worker by calling: Servers.Worker.start_link(arg)
  # {Servers.Worker, arg},
  {
    Servers.CurrentState, [ 
      init_state_with: [:hello, 10], 
      name_to_register: Servers.CurrentState
    ] 
  },
  {
    Servers.Updates, [
      init_state_with: [:goodbye], 
      name_to_register: Servers.Updates
    ]
  }
]
```

Then you *could* define your two GenServers like this:

**lib/servers/updates.ex:**

```
defmodule Servers.Updates do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(arg) do  

    GenServer.start_link(
      __MODULE__, 
      arg[:init_state_with], 
      name: arg[:name_to_register])                                       

  end

  ## Callbacks

  @impl true
  def init(state) do
    {:ok, state}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_call(:get_updates, _from, state) do
    {:reply, state, state}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_cast({:push, item}, state) do
    {:noreply, [item | state]}
  end


  ##User interface:

  def get() do
    GenServer.call(__MODULE__, :get_updates)
  end

  def add(item) do
    GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, {:push, item})
  end

end
```

**lib/servers/current_state.ex:**

```
defmodule Servers.CurrentState do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(args) do  

    GenServer.start_link(
      __MODULE__, 
      args[:init_state_with], 
      name: args[:name_to_register])

  end

  ## Callbacks

  @impl true
  def init(state) do
    IO.inspect(state, label: "The CurrentState server is starting with state")
    {:ok, state}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_call(:get_state, _from, state) do
    state_to_add = Servers.Updates.get()
    new_state = state_to_add ++ state

    {:reply, new_state, new_state}
  end


  ##User interface:

  def get() do
    GenServer.call(__MODULE__, :get_state)
  end

end
```

Then, you can test things with:

```
defmodule Servers.Go do
  def test() do
    IO.inspect("Updates has state: #{inspect Servers.Updates.get()}" )
    IO.inspect("CurrentState has state: #{inspect Servers.CurrentState.get()}" )
    :ok
  end
end
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs/servers$ iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Compiling 1 file (.ex)

The CurrentState server is starting with state: [:hello, 10]

Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> Servers.Go.test()
"Updates has state: [:goodbye]"
"CurrentState has state: [:goodbye, :hello, 10]"
:ok

iex(2)>
```

(Note the first line of output is mixed in with the server startup messages.)

However, you can use `__MODULE__` to simplify things:

**application.ex**:

```
children = [
  # Starts a worker by calling: Servers.Worker.start_link(arg)
  # {Servers.Worker, arg},

  { Servers.CurrentState,  [:hello, 10] }
  { Servers.Updates, [:goodbye] }

]
```

**lib/servers/updates.ex**:

```
defmodule Servers.Updates do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(arg) do  
                  #arg comes from child specification tuple
                  #inside the `children` list in application.ex

    #                        | module where the GenServer is defined
    #                        | 
    #                        |        | send arg to the GenServer's init() function       
    #                        V        V
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, arg, name: __MODULE__)
    #                                      ^
    #                                      |
    #                     register the specified name for this GenServer

  end

  ## Callbacks

  @impl true
  def init(state) do
    {:ok, state}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_call(:get_updates, _from, state) do
    {:reply, state, state}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_cast({:push, item}, state) do
    {:noreply, [item | state]}
  end

  ## User interface:

  def get() do
    GenServer.call(__MODULE__, :get_updates)
  end

  def add(item) do
    GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, {:push, item})
  end

end
```

lib/servers/current_state.ex:

```
defmodule Servers.CurrentState do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(arg) do  
                  #arg comes from child specification tuple
                  #inside the `children` list in application.ex

    #                        | module where the GenServer is defined
    #                        | 
    #                        |        | send arg to the GenServer's init() function       
    #                        V        V
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, arg, name: __MODULE__)
    #                                       ^
    #                                       |
    #                     register the specified name for this GenServer 
  end

  ## Callbacks

  @impl true
  def init(state) do
    IO.inspect(state, label: "The CurrentState server is starting with state")
    {:ok, state}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_call(:get_state, _from, state) do
    state_to_add = Servers.Updates.get()
    new_state = state_to_add ++ state

    {:reply, new_state, new_state}
  end

  ## User interface:

  def get() do
    GenServer.call(__MODULE__, :get_state)
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @7stud. I just stumbled upon the solution by trial and error by myself but I dont really get my head around it. I followed  the tutorial here [https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/supervisor-and-application.html] for testing this. In fact they just used the parameter for `start_link/1` as `opts` parameter in the GenServer. So, passing the `name: ` seems correct to me and as I mentioned e.g. from iex the names were known. But whatever, I changed the children list to tuples of module and start state and set the name in the GenServers themselfs. That worked.

Comment: @Sorebrez, I think you sussed things out correctly.  My suggested solution (which I just posted at the bottom) explicitly specifies the arg `name: __MODULE__` in the GenServer's `start_link()` function, however you can pass that value in from the `children` specification list as well.  Here is what I think you did wrong:  the args specified for each child's `start_link()` function in `children` needs to be a list, e.g.  `[name: Updates]`. At a minimum, the Supervisor always passes `[]` to the children when the child spec has no args.

Comment: I dont think that they have to be a list if there is only one. I did just another terrible mistake. `Updates` is also the last part of the module name and I also aliased it in the module, so the name, while calling the GenServer was translated into the full module name... So, I changed anything back and named the GenServers by atoms (they are their only instances, so that should be ok). The `children` list like mentioned in the question works by now, when using the `start_link/1` parameter as `opts` in the GenServers. I must admit that this couldnt be solved because of missing information :/

Comment: *I dont think that they have to be a list if there is only one.* -- That makes sense: elixir implicitly converts `key: value` pairs to keyword lists all the time.

Comment: I tested it, and `{SomeServer, key: val}` is equivalent to `{SomeServer, [key: val]}`, so in the *shortcut* child specification syntax, elixir implicitly converts `key: value` pairs to a keyword list, which means you can write: `{Stack, x: 10, y: "hello"}` and the arg sent to `Stack.start_link()` will be `[x: 10, y: "hello"]`.

Comment: The implicit conversion to a key word list doesn't have anything to do with the child specification syntax--it's the way tuples work: `iex(3)> {"hello", x: 10, y: 20}` => 
`{"hello", [x: 10, y: 20]}`.   When you specify a tuple with a bunch of `key: value` pairs at the end of the tuple, elixir converts all the `key: value` pairs into a keyword list.

Comment: I added an example of two supervised GenServers to the end of my answer.